# TypeScript typings for package that extends built-in node types

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I'm trying to create full typings for https://www.npmjs.com/package/keypress

I've got the basic function typed out correctly (I think) but can't figure out how to extend the declaration of `process.stdin` as this package does to make IntelliSense happy.

Specifically, `keypress` adds a `process.stdin.on('keypress', listener)` event. The `listener` has signature like `(ch: Ch, key?: Key) => void`.

I'm not sure if I need to extend the `Process` interface or maybe the `ReadStream` interface since, in theory if I'm understanding correctly, it could work on any `ReadStream`.

I'm also not sure if it's possible to inform TypeScript that it's calling `keypress()` on a `ReadStream` that adds the functionality. For instance, preventing access unless `keypress()` was called. I doubt this is possible but asking in case it could be.

Here is my current attempt:

```
declare module "keypress" {
  export default function keypress(stream: NodeJS.ReadStream): void;

  export type Ch = any; // TODO
  export type Key = {
    // TODO
    ctrl: any;
    name: string;
  };

  namespace global {
    namespace NodeJS {
      interface Process {
        stdin: NodeJS.ReadStream & {
          fd: 0; // From official node types
          on(event: "keypress", listener: (ch: Ch, key?: Key) => void): this;
        };
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried a few variations on this but I'd rather not keep shooting blind. Any pointers on this greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the official node type definitions this is what you are trying to extend: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/process.d.ts#L217

Your approach looks fine to me, however I don't think this can be done at the moment. You can use declaration merging to extend types, but you can't use it to overwrite existing members of types. Otherwise several type definitions could be in conflict with one another.

However there is a discussion about implementing a solution here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36146